# OAuth2 Roles in OIDC

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

In OAuth2 protocol, **Client** (RP in terms of OIDC) application obtains an access token, which enables it to use different services (**Resource server** role) on behalf of a **Resource Owner**.

On the other hand, in the OpenID Connect protocol, **Client** obtains 2 tokens (access and id token). Now this Client can use the access token to fetch user claims from the UserInfo endpoint.

1. Does OP (Authorization server) play role of a Resource Server here (in terms of OAuth2), and Client fetches user data on behalf of a user?
2. How is ID token used by the Client? Does Client pass this ID token to the Resource Owner's user agent (Browser) and then, user agent stores this token to enable SSO (cookie)?
3. Does Client (e.g. different one than the one that obtained the ID token) has to verify the token every time user accesses it (call OP to verify it), or Client does this only first time it gets accessed by this token and then creates security context which enables it to eliminate this request for verification at OP every time? In this case, how could this security context be implemented?
4. What is the access token used for, except for fetching user claims and why is it sent along with ID token, when Client could use ID token to access UserInfo endoint?

Answer (score 8):

First of all you must understand the purpose of tokens. Access token is a token that is good enough to access a protected resource on behalf of the end user. It is defined by OAuth 2.0 authorization framework. Now having an access token does not authenticate the end user. it simply authorize the client application to access a resource. OpenID Connect introduce the ID Token. Now this token is to be consumed by your client application. [Protocol define how this to be done](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDTokenValidation) and if valid, your client application can authenticate the end user.

**Q: Does OP (Authorization server) play role of a Resource Server here (in terms of OAuth2), and Client fetches user data on behalf of a user?**

Partially correct. [According to the protocol document](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfo), **userinfo endpoint** acts as OAuth 2.0 protected resource.

> The UserInfo Endpoint is an OAuth 2.0 Protected Resource that returns Claims about the authenticated End-User. To obtain the requested Claims about the End-User, the Client makes a request to the UserInfo Endpoint using an Access Token obtained through OpenID Connect Authentication.

**Q: How is ID token used by the Client? Does Client pass this ID token to the Resource Owner's user agent (Browser) and then, user agent stores this token to enable SSO (cookie)?**

As mentioned previously client must validate the id token and based on that it can authenticate the end user. ID token is not connected with SSO.

**Q:Does Client (e.g. different one than the one that obtained the ID token) has to verify the token every time user accesses it (call OP to verify it), or Client does this only first time it gets accessed by this token and then creates security context which enables it to eliminate this request for verification at OP every time? In this case, how could this security context be implemented?**

If you are using ID token to be consumed from a protected endpoint, then token receiving party should validate it before accepting it. One may choose to create a session after a proper token validation (session must not extend the life time of the token).

**Q: What is the access token used for, except for fetching user claims and why is it sent along with access token, when Client could use ID token to access UserInfo endoint?**

Access token is the token your should use to access OAuth 2.0 protected resources. Once the endpoint received it, endpoint can validate the access token against token introspection endpoint exposed by the authorization server ([Protocol definition of introspection](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662)). And with Openid Connect, defining of userinfo endpoint let any party with valid id token to consume it.

Comment: First, thank you for the answer. I had SSO in mind when asking the second question. Can you explain how is ID token used in this scenario? And, in plain OAuth2, does resource server always check access token at introspection endpoint of Authorization server?

Comment: Well as I have said SSO has nothing to do with ID Token. ID token is intended for the client application to consume. SSO will mostly built on cookies (between identity provider and web browser uses to complete login). Resource server can always check access token. But it may cache it or even try to create a session between client and itself to avoid introspection overhead

Comment: Thank you very much. This means that different Client (not one which received id token), accessed for the first time by the browser in session with OP, will have to access OP for authorization and then OP, checking the browser session, will authenticate user without user entering his credentials. Does OP then provide this other Client with new token? Another question, what do you mean by 'intended for client to consume'? Does client use this token only to read user informations, which can also be done by accessing userInfo endpoint with access token? So, ID token is not passed between clients?

Comment: Yes it can OP can behave in that manner. It is quite similar to how you see login with Google button and once clicked you see skip login as you are already logged into Google (from Chrome browser let's say). Yes ID token is consumed by client. It is for client to authenticate the end user. But in some scenarios, it may pass between services (ex:- your client's backend)

Comment: Can you, please, review Touffy's answers? I think many of them are not right or unprecise.

Comment: @Mike Touffy's answers does contain some valid inputs. For example, one could transfer ID token between trusted client and authenticate end user on top of it. This could be considered as SSO behaviour. But again, ID token's intent is not SSO (as I have explained).

Comment: But what if the backend needs the id_token so it can authorize by group or claim, etc?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you can be confused about that if you've read the RFCs.

1. You want to think of identity as a "resource" service? fine, but the authentication for this service is different than for RPs, so what's your point?
2. The Client exists in the User Agent (we're talking about SPAs, right?). If the ID token is in the Client, then it's in the UA (the reverse is not true). If you're thinking of server-side clients, then there is no need to forward the ID token to the UA, unless you want the UA to pass it on to another Client (e.g. for SSO). There are SSO schemes that use the ID token for convenience, but that's not the stated purpose of the ID token.
3. The whole point of JWS is that you don't need to call the OP to verify a token. You just verify the signature. That may be done by any Client, whether they're the original recipient of a token, or they get it later. Furthermore, the ID token is *not* meant to authenticate the user. Using it for SSO requires some other form of security, such as storing a related secret in an HTTP-only cookie that will not be seen by the Client. Anyway, even if you use the ID token for SSO, then the ID token is sent only in the login request. After that, the Client will get its own access token for authentication and will not use the ID token again.
4. The access token is typically short-lived (which means the Client has to contact the OP regularly, which allows the OP a chance to revoke access). The access token is sent with every authenticated request, so it should be small (i.e. not contain user information that is not useful for authentication).

Comment: 1. I want to get a clear picture of how oidc works.  How is authentication different for identity service? Why does Client need to use access token to obtain user information when it has id token? 2. How does Clients pass ID token between themselves, and I have SSO in mind? Maybe that's why id token can't be used to fetch info about user, because, for example, another Client (not the one that obtained id token) shouldn't be able to access user info? 3. How comes that ID token is not meant to authenticate the user? I understood that's the primary purpose of it.

Comment: 1. auth is different for ID service because it's provided by the OP and the ID token can (and often is) be provided as part of the login process, instead of as a separate request later.

Comment: I have explained why the ID token shouldn't be used for authentication in (4).

Comment: 2. The ID token can be stored in a cookie by the OP. So it will be included in any request (with credentials) sent to the OP's domain by any Client. So Clients don't actually pass the token around, it's the UA doing the work transparently.

Comment: Also, the ID token is not used to fetch info about the user. It **contains** info about the user. The cookie containing the ID token for SSO is usually HTTP-only (so it is not shared between Clients), and a copy of the ID token is sent in the response body of the code exchange so the current Client can see it.

Comment: 3. The primary purpose of the ID token is to tell the Client who the user is. On the other hand, the access token says what the user is allowed to do and is designed to be sent to and verified by RPs. As I have already said, the shorter payload and lifespan of the access token are why it should be used for authentication and not the ID token.

Comment: @Mike Reading your other comment on Kavindu's answer, I think I see what you've been missing all along. The tokens in OAuth and OIDC are JSON Web Tokens and usually signed but not encrypted. They **contain** data in the form of a JSON payload. You do not use the token to "fetch" information about the user, you just **read it from the token**.

Comment: 3. "To tell who the user is" or to authenticate the user, making your statement incorrect.

Comment: "You do not use the token to "fetch" information about the user, you just read it from the token." - What is the purpose of UserInfo endpoint then, if not to fetch data about user?

Comment: 1. "I have explained why the ID token shouldn't be used for authentication in (4)" - You mean for authorization? I think you mixed them.

Comment: I meant authorisation, true. And that authorisation must be authenticated by verifying the token. UserInfo does what you say, my point is that it is unnecessary if you've already got an ID token with the same information. And I stand by my comment that the ID token is not meant primarily for authentication.